# composite primary key made up of primary keys from other tables

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Hi I am trying to combine PKs from two tables (the PKs are 'video_id' and 'user_id') to create a unique list of videos watched by a specific user. I wanted this to be composite to minimize redundancy, but in the documentation only FKs seemed to be used to make composite PK. If I make it a composite FK will this still be unique (there will not be multiple rows for videos watched by the same user)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here, but the following addresses the general issue.

You have a many-to-many relationship here.  Many users can watch one video.  Many videos can be watched by one user.

The general way to record such a relationship is to use a third table.  We might call it userVideo.  It has, at a minimum, two columns, UserID and VideoID.  These are, as you suggest,  FKs referencing the PK of the User and Video tables.  Taken together, they can be the (composite) PK of this third table.  There could be more columns, such as a rating, where it would show how much the user enjoyed the video.

The combination of UserID and VideoID will be unique in this table.  If you want to store data about each time the user watched the video,  that's a different case.

Does this answer your question?